# What is the equivalent of a eutectic point for a (two-liquid)+solids system?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, water

I deal with complex phase equilibria involving solid and liquid phases at high temperature. Below is a simplified temperature-XH2O diagram for a multicomponent system at constant pressure.

[image]

(Note: The bottom axis represents the range between two end-member values of H2O contents given the arbitrary labels of '0' and '1' - i.e. It does not represent absolute concentrations of H2O).

The red dot represents the minimum water contents at which H2O and liquid (in this case a haplogranitic melt) are in equilibrium. It is similar to a eutectic; however, my understanding is that a eutectic is only between a liquid and solids. The best descriptor I can come up with is:

'The point at which the solidus is minimally saturated with respect to H2O'

This doesn't exactly roll off the tongue and I need to refer to this point for a variety of diagrams in a manuscript. Can anyone suggest a better term?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a better name for this sort of point in the scientific literature. It doesn't exactly shock me if you refer it as an eutectic point, but you'd have to explain it in its first occurrence in the text.

Otherwise, just assign a letter to it (just avoid “lambda point”!), and use that throughout your paper.